# Python: Difficulty understanding double preceding function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, range

in the process of learning python, stuck at understanding this piece of code. It works, and the book required me to test it, which I have successfully, but cannot understand how the first index ends up in the code.

```
def double_preceding(values):
    """(list) -> NoneType

    Replace each item in the list with twice the value of the preceding item, and replace the first item with 0.

    >>> L = [l , 2 , 3]
    >>> double_preceding(L)
    >>> L
    (0, 2, 4]
    """

    if values != []:
        temp = values[0]
        values[0] = 0
        for i in range(1, len(values)):
            double = 2 * temp
            temp = values[i]
            values[i] = double
```

The range starts from index 1, which would skip index 0, so how does the output of 2 get in there(from the doctest)? That would mean value 1 was doubled, but the range skips index 0...?

And another question, doesn't `values[0] = 0` change the value in [0] to 0? How did the value "1" end up being doubled in the output list?

It's such simple code, but has made me lose my mind.
Thanks in advance! Appreciate your time

Comment: The code returns `[0, 2, 4]`, for `L = [1 , 2 , 3]`, there is a l instead of 1 on L.

Comment: The way the value `1` (the original `L[0]`) ends up getting doubled (so `2` ends up in the new `L[1]`) is that `temp` variable. First you copy `values[0]` into `temp` before you overwrite `values[0]`, so `2 * temp` is double the original value. And, likewise, you always copy `values[i]` into `temp` before you overwrite it with `double`, so you end up with double the original `values[i]` in each `values[i+1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting loop, and I will walk you through how it works.

The statement `if values != []:` checks if the loop is empty. and if not, it proceeds.

The statement `temp = values[0]` stores the original value of `values[0]` in temp. This is how the program knows to double the 1. So in our example, the value of `temp` would be 1.

The next step `values[0] = 0` sets the value of the first element to 0, but we still know what the original value of the array was, since we stored it in `temp`.

Now we start the loop. The loop goes from 1 all the way to the end of the loop.

The variable double holds the value of `temp` multiplied by 2. So in our example, since `temp` is 1, double holds 2.

Now the statement `temp = values[i]` would store the current iteration value of the loop in `temp`. In our example, we would be at the first iteration, so since `values[1]` is 2, temp has 2 in it.

Finally, the statement `values[i] = double` stores the value of double in the array. currently, we are at index 1, and since `double` is 2, that is what that index will have.

We can loop through this sequence again. Currently, our array has {0, 2, 3}. In the next iteration of the for, `double` is `temp*2`. Since `temp` was 2, `double` is 4. Now that value of double is stored in the second index of the array. The line `temp = values[i]` would store 4 in `temp`, but it doesn't matter since the loop is finished, since the length of the array is 3, and the loop only repeats when i < 3.

When we are finished the final array is {0, 2, 4}.

Answer (score 2):

```
def double_preceding(values):
    """(list) -> NoneType

    Replace each item in the list with twice the value of the preceding item, and replace the first item with 0.

    >>> L = [1 , 2 , 3]
    >>> double_preceding(L)
    >>> L
    (0, 2, 4]
    """

    if values != []:
        temp = values[0] # temp is 1 now
        values[0] = 0 #sets 1 to 0
        for i in range(1, len(values)): # start at second item in array and go until end
            double = 2 * temp # double it by the last (which is stored in temp)
            temp = values[i] # temp is now equal to the item we just doubled (the "preceding item")
            values[i] = double # change the value of the item at the index so it is actually the doubled item
```